# Turn model into JSON and pass it into JavaScript setOnLoadCallBack

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

Below is my view. I have modified it to display how I would like it to work. I have a graph that is drawn when the page is loaded. My model contains the data it needs. I have to transform it to JSON (right?) and then pass it into the generateGraph, but the setOnLoadCallBack is my problem. I can't figure out how to create the JSON string before the setOnLoadCallBack is called.

```
@model IEnumerable<FHWebUserInterface.Models.Weight>
<div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

<div id="linechart_material"></div>



@{
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var weightsAsJsonString = serializer.Serialize(Enumerable.Select(Model, weight =>
        new
        {
            date = weight.Date,
            value = weight.Value
        }));
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', { packages: ['corechart', 'imagelinechart'] });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawVisualization(weightsAsJsonString) {

        // Removed the body            

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization(weightsAsJsonString));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to render your json somewhere in JavaScript block like this (i've added it before `google.setOnLoadCallback` call):

```
@model IEnumerable<FHWebUserInterface.Models.Weight>
<div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

<div id="linechart_material"></div>



@{
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var weightsAsJsonString = serializer.Serialize(Enumerable.Select(Model, weight =>
        new
        {
            date = weight.Date,
            value = weight.Value
        }));
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', { packages: ['corechart', 'imagelinechart'] });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function drawVisualization(weightsAsJsonString) {

        // Removed the body            

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    // here is my change
    var weightsAsJsonString = @weightsAsJsonString; // so it will render your C# object from server side here on client side

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization(weightsAsJsonString));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time!